# Is my probability tree diagram correct

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

If the last two days have been sunny, then 95% of the time tomorrow will be sunny.

If yesterday was cloudy and today is sunny, then 70% of the time, tomorrow will be sunny.

If yesterday was sunny and today is cloudy, then 60% of the time, tomorrow will be cloudy.

If the last two days have been cloudy, then 80% of the time, tomorrow will be cloudy.

So my tree diagram is as follows. I have completed it for all 16 possibilities, but I only drew up part of it. I just want to know if my approach is correct.

[image]

A transition matrix would look like this, and I can fill the rest of the blanks accordingly.

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
State & \text{SS} & \text{SC} & \text{CC} & \text{CS}\\
\hline
SS & 0.9025 & .0475 & 0.03 & 0.02 \\
SC & ... & ... & ... &...\\
CS & ... & ... & ...&...\\
CC & ...&...&...&...
\end{array}
$$

Comment: And what are you trying to find in this Markov process? The diagram is indeed correct, but…

Comment: Your approach looks correct assuming that your transition matrix is a transition two time units into the future, if that makes any sense, i..e., a transition from $SS \rightarrow SS$ implies that if day 1 and day 2 were sunny, then the probability of day 3 and day 4 being sunny is $0.9025$.

Comment: Yes so it is a system in which a state is composed of two days. And the weather of any day depends on the two days prior.